# If possible: How can I apply z-index in Wordpress over a media library image?

Tags: wordpress, image, graphics, z-index

I'm trying to create a membership card for our nonprofit with a dynamically-updating date. Is it possible to add a z-index element (such as a shortcode) on top of a Wordpress media library content (an image I've uploaded?).

Basically, I need to add a dynamic date (current month and year) to a digital version of a membership card for our nonprofit members. I've tried svg and can't get it to upload to media library, even with the "Safe SVG" plugin, so I am trying to find another way to add this dynamic element to a graphic. I've tried designing it in CSS, too, and got pretty close, but couldn't get "Outdoor Women's Alliance" to line up correctly, so I stopped there. What I currently have on the site is a static .png that I'll have to update each month and looks like this:

[image]

What I would prefer is where it has the date (July 2018), I want to be able to add a dynamic date that will update at the start of each new month so I don't have to create a new graphic each month and upload it — it will just update to the new month (e.g. next month will auto-update to say "August 2018), etc. and then will update with the year changes as well.

I have a plugin that helps dynamically set month/year to update each month using a shortcode, so I was thinking I would remove the date on this card and try to overlay the shortcode in html using positioning and z-index. (But it would be even better to not have to use a plugin, of course.)

P.S. The card doesn't have to look like this, but should have the name of our organization, the logo, and the "Guide Member" title (as well as the date :). And yes, I know membership cards should have the member's name on it, but I haven't figured out how to populate that from our list of members yet. :)

Any ideas on z-index or inserting dynamic dates on top of images? Is this possible or is there a better workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Just replace your image by removing Month and Year and set font-family to newly added text (class text) so that it can match the text "Guide Member"

```
 <style type="text/css">
        .container {
    position: relative;
    }
   .text {
   position: absolute;
   top: 75%;
   left: 10%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   font-size: 22px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
        </style>
   <div class="container">
  <img src="test.png" alt="Snow" style="">
  <div class="text">November 2018</div>

</div>
```